# Bokeh change tick label from a number to text

Tags: python, bokeh

I am plottings a grading system using plot.circle. I am trying to represent the grades as label's and not numbers. E.g. as A+=1, A=2, B=3, C=4, D=5.

The points plotted on the graph is a fraction of the grades. E.g. point1 = 1.6, which would lie between A+ and A.

I could not find a way to change the labels of an axis to my represent my grades' labels, so I tried to create a second axis, a categorical axis, and hide the original axis (the one containing the grading's values.)

The problem I'm having with this approach is that my categorical axis' ticks is not lining up with original axis' ticks.
The Single interval ticker ensures that both axis number of ticks matches. but the ticks still do not align.

When I set the y_range of the original axis, the major ticks starts at the bottom of the chart and ends at the top. The categorical axis behaves differently.

Here is my code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models.tickers import SingleIntervalTicker
from bokeh.models import CategoricalAxis, FactorRange

output_file("axes.html")
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [1,2.3,3,4.5,5,6]

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
#p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, y_range=[0,10])
p.circle(x, y, size=10)

s_i_ticker = SingleIntervalTicker()
s_i_ticker.interval = 1
s_i_ticker.num_minor_ticks = 0
p.yaxis[0].ticker= s_i_ticker
#p.yaxis[0].bounds = (1, 10)
#p.yaxis[0].visible = False

factors = ["A+", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
f_range = FactorRange(factors=factors)
help(CategoricalAxis)
p.extra_y_ranges = {"foo": f_range}
p.circle(x, factors, color="blue", y_range_name="foo")
new_axis = CategoricalAxis(y_range_name="foo")
#new_axis.bounds = (1, 10)
#new_axis.ticker= s_i_ticker
p.add_layout(new_axis, 'left')

show(p)
```

I cannot post a screenshot of the resulting chart as I cannot post images on stackoverflow yet. The code is runnable as is.

Any solutions? Ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I solved my issue by using a workaround:

```
plot.text(..)
```

I am plotting text as 'watermarks' in bands across the chart so that it displays as an indicator on what that area mean. E.g. Points in the area is in the 'B' grade area.

Comment: could  you be a bit more specific ?